# Naming convention for VBA modules?

Tags: vba, vb6, naming-conventions

I never really know how to name VBA modules.  Should I:

1. Use a prefix, like basName or modName.
2. Not use a prefix, like Module.  (But avoid restricted words)
3. Something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not prefix! Name the module appropriately for what it does.

Comment: Yeah, I feel pretty ridiculous using a prefix because I'm trying to get rid of hungarian in my VBA code.  Just not sure best way to create unique names.  Most of my modules are single words.

Comment: Any thought on singular vs. plural names?

Comment: Be careful that you do not also have a procedure of the same name.

Comment: Don't just bark out orders!  Provide the rationale behind your opinion.

Comment: @raven - I would if it were something more than opinion. This opinion however has been common among developers I've met. Not universal but common.

Answer (score 3):

Granted, this is taking the way back machine, but when I did extensive VBA development, I always named my modules with a prefix of something like "bas" because the names of Class modules and Global modules in combination had to be unique (i.e. you couldn't have a Global module named Foo and Class module named Foo). I believe the same was true of VB6 but that was many moons ago.

Comment: I think this also helps to ensure that modules do not contain procedures of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I prefix standard modules with M, class modules with C, and userforms with U.  In the VBE, I turn off the folder view in the project explorer to show all of the modules.  The prefixes keep them nicely sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A prefix can be useful just for the sake of making related modules appear next to each other in the project window. I use prefixes like "numeric" or "test" all the time in lieu of some other way to group them. But you probably don't need something like "mod"...